# Do similar matrices have the same determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $A$, $P$ and $D$ be $n \times n$ matrices, with $P$ being invertible. If $A = PDP^{-1}$, then $\det A = \det D$

I used an example to show its false, but just looking for verification to see if it is indeed false.

Comment: If you have an example, perhaps you could show it.  But I suspect it is more likely to be true

Comment: The determinant of a product is the product of the determinants

Comment: ah i must have made a mistake, so it is indeed true

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are similar. Then there exists a nonsingular matrix $S$ such that
$[S^{-1}AS=B]$ by definition.
Then we have
\begin{align*}
&\det(B)\\
&=\det(S^{-1}AS)\\
&=\det(S)^{-1}\det(A)\det(S) &\text{(by multiplicative properties of determinants)}\\
&=\det(A) &\text{(since determinants are just numbers, hence commutative)}
\end{align*}

Thus, we obtain $\det(A)=\det(B)$ as required.