# Prove that $\det(I_n-TAT^{-1})=\det(I_n-A)$

Tags: determinant, matrix-equations

Prove that $\det(I_n-TAT^{-1})=\det(I_n-A)$ for any matrix $T\in\mathbb R_{n\times n}$ with $\det(T)\ne0$.

Comment: Have a look at: [Do similar matrices have the same determinant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3553298)

Comment: Hint: Write $I_n = T I_n T^{-1}$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do similar matrices have the same determinant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3553298/do-similar-matrices-have-the-same-determinant)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please state what you have tried. Can you prove that $\det (TAT^{-1}) = \det A$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $T,A \in \operatorname{GL}_n$.

We know that $\operatorname{det}(AB)=\operatorname{det}(A)\operatorname{det}(B)$. Therefore:

$\operatorname{det}(I_n - TAT^{-1}) = \operatorname{det}(TT^{-1} - TAT^{-1}) = \operatorname{det}(T)\operatorname{det}(I_n - A)\operatorname{det}(T^ {-1}) \\
= \operatorname{det}(TT^{-1})\operatorname{det}(I_n - A)$

which delivers the desired result.